Solve $|x|>|x-1|$

Solve $|x|>|x-1|$

$\dfrac{|x|}{|x-1|}>1  \Leftrightarrow \left| \dfrac{x}{x-1} \right| >1$
$\dfrac{x}{x-1} > 1 \tag{1}$ or $-\dfrac{x}{x-1}>1 \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{x}{x-1}<-1 \tag{2}$
For $(1)$:
If $x-1 > 0 \Leftrightarrow x>1$, $\ \ \ x-1<x \Leftrightarrow -1<0$
If $x-1<0 \Leftrightarrow x<1$, $\ \ \ x-1>x \Leftrightarrow -1>0$
For $(2)$:
If $x>1$, $\ \ \ -x+1 >x \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}>x$
If $x<1$, $\ \ \ -x+1<x \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{2}<x$
So to summarize:
$x>1, -1<0 \tag{a}$
$x<1, -1>0 \tag{b}$
$x>1, \dfrac{1}{2}>x \tag{c}$
$x<1, \dfrac{1}{2}<x \tag{d}$
$(b)$ contradicts itself, as does $(c)$, so those two are discarded. From $(a)$ and $(b)$, I deduce the interval of $x$ that works to be $(\dfrac{1}{2},1)\bigcup(1, \infty)$ which makes sense because $x=1$ in the denominator makes the fraction undefined. The problem is the original question is not in fraction form, and indeed $x=1$ works fine there. So is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach of putting the absolute values on one side of the inequality? Is there another way to solve this without incurring this mistake? I'm a bit uncomfortable with solving inequalities with absolute values on both sides.

There is nothing wrong, but if you divide by $|x-1|$ then you have to treat the case $x=1$ separately.

There are many ways to solve this. For example you can consider the cases $x < 0$, $0 \le x \le 1$, and $x > 1$ in the original inequality.

Actually the solution is almost obvious if you recognize $|x|$ as “the distance from $x$ to $0$” and $|x-1|$ as “the distance from $x$ to $1$.” – Which real numbers are closer to $1$ than to $0$?

@MartinR That is indeed the most intuitive way to think about the problem.

Also $|x|>|x-1| \iff x^2 > (x-1)^2 \iff ...$

@MartinR It also incidentally makes it easy to see that in the complex plane, the solutions to $|z| > |z-1|$ are exactly the half-plane ${ z\in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > \frac{1}{2} }$.

@DanielSchepler: Yes, that is how I memorize that $z \mapsto (z-1)/(z+1)$ maps the right halfplane to the unit disk.

It is usually easier (when possible) to work in cases, where the cases are determined by the expressions in absolute value. Here, we have three cases: $x \le 0$, $0 < x \le 1$, and $x > 1$.
When $x \le 0$, the argument of both absolute values are negative. Therefore, the inequality becomes
$$-x > -(x - 1) \iff -x > -x + 1 \iff 0 > 1$$
which is a contradiction, so this case has no solutions.
When $0 < x \le 1$, the argument to the absolute value on the right side remains negative, but the left argument is now positive. Therefore, the inequality becomes
$$x > -(x - 1) \iff x > -x + 1 \iff 2 x > 1 \iff x > \frac{1}{2}$$
so the overall solution for this case would be $\frac{1}{2} < x \le 1$.
Finally, when $x > 1$, both absolute value arguments are positive. So we have
$$x > x - 1 \iff 0 > -1$$
which is always true. The overall solution for this case would be $x > 1$.
Taking the union of the cases, we find that the overall solution is
$$\boxed{x > \frac{1}{2}}$$
While a bit cumbersome, this technique of breaking down absolute value terms into cases is quite general and does not "miss" any cases (because all of the steps are "reversible").

For the cases to be truly reversible, you should use $\iff$ instead of $\implies$ for the logic in each of the cases.

How did you come up with the three cases $x \leq 0, 0<x \leq 1, x>1$ from looking at the problem?

@ronaldchristenkkson You can tell from the arguments to the absolute value. On the left, $x$ gives $0$ as a "changing point". On the right, $x - 1$ gives $1$ as a "changing point".

Another way is by squaring both sides (not negative), that is
$$|x|>|x-1| \iff \sqrt{x^2}>\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} \iff x^2>x^2-2x+1 \iff x>\frac 12$$
which is indeed the right solution.

Why not read it from the drawing?
Most people know that the drawing of $|x|$ is a $90°$ angle, and $f(x-1)$ equals $f(x)$, shifted one unit to the right, so you get:

Question: when is the green higher than the red?

The original inequality is not equivalent to your fractional inequality.
When you move to the fractional inequality, you invoke the caveat "$x \neq 1$" because you divide by $|x-1|$. This means all solutions to the fractional inequality will be solutions to the original inequality, and you must check whether $x=1$ is a solution to the original inequality separately.
